# How can i edit the data i fetch from google calendar in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-calendar-api

I managed to fetch data from google calendar by following the google calendar API tutorial in this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android.How can i edit those data i fetched from google calendar in android studio?

Comment: Can you please post the code you have written so far?

Comment: i dont have any code in update.

Comment: If you want to update an event that you get in a calendar, then try to check this [`Events: update`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) if it can help you. By using this, you can update or change the metadata of the event in a calendar. Check this [example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#examples) on how to update event in calendar using JAVA.

Comment: This is a new function right? I will insert this to my java class?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in adding events.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onAddEventClicked(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()  + 60 * 60 * 1000;

    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,endTime);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

    intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Create Event");
    intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION,  "description");
    intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "My Guest House");
    intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=YEARLY");

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: You should paste this code as part of your question, not an answer